# How can I initialize and dynamically allocate an int pointer member in an array of structs?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

How can I initialize and dynamically allocate an int pointer that is in an array of structs?

My program allows me to print **enroll[0].grades[x]**, but when I try to access any other index value of enroll other than 0 (such as **enroll[1].grades[x]** or **enroll[2].grades[x]**), my program segmentation faults.

Here's my code...

How can I make **enroll[2].grades[x]**, for example, initialize and equal zero?

**In my struct:**

```
struct Enroll
{
        int *grades;
};
```

**In main:**

```
struct Enroll *enroll = (struct Enroll *) calloc(count.enroll, 10 * sizeof(struct Enroll));

enroll->grades = (int *) calloc(count.grades, 10 * sizeof(int));
```

**In functions:**

```
enroll[x].grades[y];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allocate memory for number of struct Enrollements

```
struct Enroll *p = calloc(count.enroll, sizeof(struct Enroll));
```

Now you have the number of structures to be filled in and what you need is memory for the int pointer to hold values and the number of `int` pointers is `count.enroll`

```
for(i=0;i<count.enroll;i++)
{
   p[i].grades = calloc(count.grades,sizeof(int)); 
   // Fill in the values
}
```

PS: Alternatively you can go for `malloc()` followed by `memset()`

Comment: Can you give me an example malloc() and memset() is this situation?

Comment: @goatmeal Just replace calloc by malloc `struct Enroll *p = malloc(count.enroll *sizeof(struct Enroll));`in the above code and right after it do `memset(p, 0, sizeof(struct Enroll) * count.enroll));`

Answer (score 0):

In main you should have

```
struct Enroll *enroll =  calloc(count.enroll, sizeof(struct Enroll));

for(int i = 0; i < count.enroll ;i++)
{
    enroll[i].grades =  calloc(count.grades,  sizeof(int));
}
```

In your code you have not allocated memory for each integer pointer.

Comment: Casting malloc() and family is not required